# How to Create a Web-Based Drawing Canvas

Tags: php, web-applications

How to Create a Web-Based Drawing Canvas ? or any API is available to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new standards way to achieve this is the html 5 canvas element:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element